# Recursive Tree Structure - Restarting method / calling recursion inside the if(___) space

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, tree, nodes

I am trying to create a recursive tree data structure for following problem: given a set of positive integers (Items with positive values), I want to divide them into a fixed number of subsets (put them in Containers or bins) so that the sum of the elements in all subsets is equal.

For simplicity purpose I have renamed all attributes. 
I have a Node Class here that holds all the respective children nodes and calls their insert() function. If my success base case (All items have been distributed)  is met, all I care about is printing the current state and ending my recursive function.

Basically in each node I try to place one item into a container. If it fails (because the item (or Integer) exceeds the maximum allowed value), I want the parent node to create a new node and reattempt the thing. with its next container. If all containers have been tested, return false.

Unfortunately, I am struggling with two things. Here's the Code.

```
package DataStructure_Finding_Equal_Sharings_444_Prjct3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

    //List Holding Items still needed to be distributed
    private Items items;

    private List<Node> children;

    private List<Container> containerlist;

    private int containercount = 0;

    private Item nodeItem;

    public Node(List <Container> containerlist, Items item){
    this.Items = item;
    this.containerlist = containerlist;
    this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean insert(){

        //BASECASE 1 : Combination Found
        if(items.getAllItems().isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Combination Found:" +                 containerlist.toString());
            return true;
        }

        //BASECASE 2 : All Children Created, All Container attempted to     fill
        else if (containercount +1 ==  containerlist.size()){
            return false;
        }

        else{
            //Check If This Node has been Initiated already. If Not,     Initiate by Taking Item
            if(nodeItem == null){

                nodeItem = items.takeItem();

                //If True (GiveItem was Succesful), Item is Stored in this Node. Afterwards New Node will be created.
                if(containerlist.get(containercount).giveItem(nodeItem)){
                    Node childNode = new Node(containerlist, items);
                    children.add(childNode);

                    //If Child Returns False, Try Next Child
                    boolean test = children.get(containercount).insert(containerlist, items);
                    if( test == false){
                        containercount++;
                        insert();
                        return false;
                    }
                    //Child Returns True: Solution Found!
                    else{
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                //If False, Item did not fit in this Node, tell parent this child is dead. Put Item Item Back (This Never Happened)
                else{
                    items.returnItem(nodeItem);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //Item was already assigned to Node, this is a revisited node
            else {
                //Create the next Node for another attempt
                Node childNode = new Node(containerlist, items);
                children.add(childNode);

                //If Child Returns False, Try Next Child
                if(childNode.insert() == false){
                    containercount++;
                    insert(); //Restart this node method with containercount                    increased, so that a new attempt can be made
                    return false; //end this attempt
                    }
                    else{
                        return true;
                    }
            }

}
```

*Problem One:*

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code `
```

`- Erroneous sym type:`

`ultimatetalerproblem.Node.insert at   DataStructure_Finding_Equal_Sharings_444_Prjct3.Node.insert(Node.java:60[...]`

`Users/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1`

Is referring to this

`//If Child Returns False, Try Next Child
boolean test = children.get(containercount).insert(containerlist, items)`

*And Problem 2:*

`insert();`

Basically what I am attempting is to just restart the same method with the parameter `containercount` set to +1. However when I call insert(), I am really creating a new method, so I feel like I am not doing something right.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Items Class

```
package DataStructure_Finding_Equal_Sharings_444_Prjct3;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Items {

private ArrayList<Item> items;
private int totalCount;
private int totalvalue; 

public Items(){
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    this.totalCount = 0;
    this.totalvalue = 0;
}

public void addItem(int value){
    this.items.add(new Item(value));
}

public void returnitem(Item item){
    items.add(item);
}

public Coin takeItem(){
    Coin tempItem = items.get(0);
    items.remove(0);
    return tempItem;
}

public int getTotalCount(){
    return this.totalCount;
}

public int getTotalvalue(){
    return this.totalvalue;
}

public List getAllItems(){
    return items;
}

}
```

Container Class:

```
package ultimatetalerproblem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An Container holding items.
 * <br/>
 * The number of items it can hold is not limited, but the added value of the
 * items it holds may not be higher than the given maximal size.
 */
public class Container {

/**h
 * maximal allowed added value of items.
 */
private int totalValue;
/**
 * current added value of items.
 */
private int currentSize;
/**
 * list of items in container.
 */
private List<Item> items;

/**
 * construct new container with given maximal size.
 *
 * @param totalValue
 * @param subListValue
 */

public Container(int subListValue) {
    this.totalValue = subListValue;
    this.currentSize = 0;
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
}

/**
 * adds given item to this container, and increases the currentSize of the container by
 * value of item. If item does not fit, it will not be put in the container and
 * false will be returned.
 *
 * @param item item to put in container
 * @return true if item fit in container, false otherwise
 */

public boolean giveItem(Item item) {

    if (currentSize + item.getValue() <= totalValue) {
        items.add(item);
        currentSize += item.getValue();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; // item didn't fit
    }
}

/**
 * removes given item from container and reduces the currentSize of the container by
 * value of item.
 *
 * @param item item to remove from container
 * @return wheter item was succesfully removed.
 */

/**
 * returns the number of items in this container (NOT the added value of the
 * items).
 *
 * @return number of items in this container
 */

public int numberOfItems() {
    return items.size();
}

public int getTotalValue(){

    return totalValue;
}

public List<Item> getitems(){

    return items;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        res += items.get(i) + " ";
    }
    res += "    Size: " + currentSize + " (max: " + totalValue + ")";
    return res;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the errors below so far:

1) As i didn't have the Item class, i changed to Integer .

2) In Node constructor, should be this.items, not this.Items

You should remove Coin and use Item.